# Configure Slack alerts in Spinnaker

Tags: slack, spinnaker

When a spinnaker pipeline fails, we can see the following:

```
Spinnaker Alerts Bot APP [3:24 PM]
Stage failed for APP_NAME
Stage STAGE_NAME for APP_NAME's PIPELINE_NAME has failed

OTHER STUFF FROM NOTIFICATION CONFIG PANEL OF STAGE

Spinnaker   Today at 3:24 PM
```

It's easy to configure the "OTHER STUFF", but what about the first 3 lines, not seeing a place in Spinnaker UI to do this, perhaps in the configuration files on server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an update for more recent version of spinnaker, 1.16.5: the custom message is editable for each notification type (start, fail, done). Doesn't seem that you can put html in it, but you can put markup. I don't know at what version of spinnaker the contents of this post got implemented, I just know it holds for 1.16.5.

Also once you have configured one of your pipelines to use Notification, you can copy the JSON for the notification to other pipelines to easily configure them identically (or as a starting point).

So I have the following JSON for our Slack notifications, notice the pipeline parameters used and their bold markup:

```
  "notifications": [
    {
      "address": "spinnaker-notifications",
      "level": "pipeline",
      "message": {
        "pipeline.failed": {
          "text": "SERVICE_NAME: *${ parameters['SERVICE_NAME'] }*\nSERVICE_VERSION: *${ parameters['SERVICE_VERSION'] }*"
        },
        "pipeline.starting": {
          "text": "SERVICE_NAME: *${ parameters['SERVICE_NAME'] }*\nSERVICE_VERSION: ${ parameters['SERVICE_VERSION'] }"
        }
      },
      "type": "slack",
      "when": [
        "pipeline.failed"
      ]
    }
  ],
```

The message text is easy to configure via the Notifications dialog, just the JSON contains the embedded \n etc.

Comment: This is the better answer!!

Answer (score 2):

It's not documented, but if you edit the JSON of the notification, you can add a `customMessage` field, and that will override the default three-line message.

For example, change the `notifications` field in your stage JSON to:

```
"notifications": [
    {
      "address": "my-slack-channel",
      "customMessage": "this will replace all three of the standard message lines, and can contain HTML",
      "level": "stage",
      "type": "slack",
      "when": [
        "stage.failed"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

and you'll see:

```
Spinnaker Alerts Bot APP [3:24 PM]
this will replace all three of the standard message lines, and can contain HTML

Spinnaker   Today at 3:24 PM
```

Comment: Exciting, thx, I'll try that tomorrow then I can accept/upvote. Do you know if expressions are allowed in the customMessage string?

Comment: @Oliver yeah, the messages will be run through the SpEL processor, so you can use expressions in them. There are a couple of extra, non-SpEL expressions you can use, too: `{{executionId}}` (the id of the execution) and `{{link}}` (the URL of the execution, deep linked to that stage)

Comment: OK so I checked and it worked partially so +1: unfortunately the title does not get changed, ie the line in my question sample "Stage failed for APP_NAME" remains the same. The line after it contains the custom message that I wrote, and I was indeed able to use parameters from the pipeline via `${ parameters['...'] }`. I didn't try the deep link which is there by default. Is there a way to find out what the default message string is?

Comment: So I'm guessing that https://github.com/spinnaker/echo/blob/master/echo-notifications/src/main/groovy/com/netflix/spinnaker/echo/notification/SlackNotificationAgent.groovy is the code for the Slack notification, it shows your customMessage, and shows that the title is hard-coded to the return value of getNotificationTitle() which always includes the Application name. I'd have to somehow override that function. in the plugin after installing spinnaker, not really an option.